# JQuery not working consistently for a form_for button

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4

I am still learning rails and am having an issue with my submit button. I have a bootstrap button to "submit request" in rails, and would like to have a JQuery box with a message fade in once the button is pressed. Currently the button only works some of the time, and not at other times, and I can't figure out why it is acting inconsistently.

The JQuery codeis below:

```
    <script src=" https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
       $("form").submit(function(){
          $("#processing").fadeIn(1000);
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Here is the code for my form and the JQuery action:

```
    <%= form_for (@request), :html=> {:id => "form"} do |f| %>

      <%= f.check_box(:option1) %>
      <%= f.label(:option1, "Option 1") %><br>

      <%= f.check_box(:option2) %>
      <%= f.label(:option2, "Option 2") %><br>

     <center><%= f.submit "Submit Request", class: "btn btn-primary", data: {disable_with: "Processing..."} %></center>

    <% end %>


    <br><br>
    <center><div id="processing" style="width:550;height:65px;display:none;background-color:darkgrey; vertical-align:middle">
      <font color="white"><br>Your request is processing.</font></div><br></center>
```

Comment: Did you check your browser console for errors??

Comment: Is the button dynamically being generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are you using turbolinks? Jquery event document ready doesn't work properly with turbolinks. Try to remove turbolinks from your application.js file and test it

Comment: You're welcome. If it solved you problem, please mark the answer =)